# How to restrict Endpoint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a multi-vendor marketplace with django. I have an endpoint for retrieving, updating and deleting a product that belongs to a store like this: localhost:8000/name-of-store/int:product_id. Note: "name-of-code" is the slug of the store.

This is the code below:

```
class EditItemAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
serializer_class = ItemSerializer
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def get_queryset(self):
    item = Item.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    print(item)
    
    return item
```

With this code, if I append the id of a product that does not belong to a particular store in the url above i.e I do  localhost:8000/name-of-store/5, where 5 is the id of a product that belongs to another store, it gets the product. How do I implement some kind of restriction such that if I try append the id of a product not belonging to the shop whose slug is in the url I get a 401 message?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you mean "name-of-store" in your Note: "name-of-code"? If so just include that in your item filter under `get_queryset`

Comment: Hi Stoobish. Yeah,  I meant "name-of-store". Thanks for your suggestion, that's what what I later did. I got the slug of the store from the URL using "self.kwargs", used that to get the appropriate store and then filtered the item by that store.

Comment: great, if that solved it, can you kindly mark question as closed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by overriding the put/patch(depends on the method you are using)
Ex.

```
def put(self, request,name-of-store,product_id):
    # Write validation for product_id here and return 401.
    return super().put(request,name-of-store,product_id )
```

**Note:** You can also implement this logic in the permission class as well.